# Hosted jQuery plugin vs npm package, what's the difference?

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, webpack

Newbie front-end developer here. In the old days, to include a 3rd party jquery plugin, the normal approach is to include a `<script>` tag in the HMTL, which usually references some hosted js/css files.

Now with npm packages, you normally do `npm install package_name` and `import xx from 'package-name'`. And there is also webpack that comes into play, which only makes things more confusing. I know that when using webpack, you are not supposed to bundle 3rd party jquery plugins to the final bundle.js output. Does it mean that when deployed, it is recommended to use the hosted css/js files for resolving the dependencies?

What's the difference between the two approaches? Is one for developement and the other for deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Importing 3rd party modules (and not only) it helps writing more modular code and helps to split your code into multiple files. The advantage of this pattern is that you don't have to resolve manually the dependencies by defining them explicitly on your html scripts. It is quite possible,  when a project is growing, to lose control with all these files, mess up the order that you include them and finally break everything. In the case of the import, you define within your functionality what are the dependencies and you don't rely on the order that you include the files in the html document. The import is not supported yet natively from all the browsers and even from node up till now. So, here is when the Babel and the webpack come in play. As you develop, the imports should be translated to something that browsers and node understand and you can use babel for this (never worked with Webpack but possibly you can do the same thing). Babel and Webpack will ensure that the dependencies will be resolved and finally will produce another js file that it will be compiled to pure javascript that browsers and node will understand. Webpack and babel should be used both for development and deployment.

There are other patterns that you can use to include modules like the amd pattern and the common.js pattern (it is very similar to the import).

Answer (score 0):

The difference, i think, is that new tendences in web development have new requirements, for example lazy load of resources, so now, the old way of including scripts in html is not usefull because this does not meet the requirements